# Default.xml won't apply to page in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, theme, default.xml

I have looked at other answers, and there is no problem in my path or my xml file I believe, In my own theme I am extending the blank theme and the blank theme did not contain any `layout/default.xml` so I added it from the luma theme and making changes there did take effect on the page.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

          <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="sidebar-additional" remove="true" /> 

        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I am placing my default.xml file in `/app/design/frontend/vendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Where vendor is my own vendor name, I have tried to make errors in the xml but no errors come up in the logs, seems as if Magento does not `find` my `default.xml`

Might be unrelated but the `pub/static` folder should contain a copy of my theme, but there is no `/Magento_Theme/`

folder there, I am assuming it should be there.

For a coworker doing the exact same procedure as me it worked fine, but instead using `Magento-Luma as parent theme.`

Comment: have you set mytheme as content theme configuration in backend then it should work default.xml file

Comment: Yes, my theme is working correctly and I am able to style it to my will. The only problem I am having is that my default.xml just won't apply. Magento is not recognizing it at all. It is as if it does not allow me to extend/overwrite Magento_Theme folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2996#issuecomment-174435731

Had to change a value in the database for my theme, changing it from virtual to physical.